# Error al correr jsonwebtoken en docker con typescript

Tags: typescript, docker, docker-compose, jsonwebtoken

Tengo un proyecto en typescript que contine un backend en node + typescript que funciona con la injeccion de dependencias.

Tengo la libreria jsonwebtoken para gestionar los tokens.
he instaldo tanto jsonwebtokens como @types/jsonwebtokens

En dev(windows) funciona todo perfecto pero cuando corro el docker-compose y levanta el proyecto en produccion (ubuntu) salta este error:

`src/Contexts/Shared/domain/value-object/Jwt.ts(3,17): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jsonwebtoken' or its corresponding type declarations.`

Os dejo el dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12.16.3-slim

WORKDIR /code

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
```

Os dejo el docker-composer:

```
version: '3.8'

services:  
  application_backend-platform:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "npm run build && npm run start:application_backend-platform"
    ports:
      - 4300:4300
    environment:
      - MONGO_URL=
    volumes:
      - .:/code:delegated
      - node_modules:/code/node_modules:delegated
   volumes:
      node_modules:
```

Aqui esta el packaje-json para que veias que esta instalada la dependencia:

```js
{
  "name": "typescript-node",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "repository": {
    "url": ""
  },
  "license": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10.15.0",
    "npm": ">=6.7.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev:application_backend-platform": "SET NODE_ENV=dev && ts-node-dev --ignore-watch node_modules --inspect=0.0.0.0:9267 src/apps/Application_backend-platform/server.ts",
    "test": "npm run test:unit && npm run test:features",
    "test:unit": "SET NODE_ENV=test && jest",
    "test:features": "SET NODE_ENV=test && cucumber-js -p default",
    "start:saas_backend": "NODE_ENV=production node dist/src/apps/Saas_backend/server",
    "start:application_backend-platform": "NODE_ENV=production node dist/src/apps/Application_backend-platform/server",
    "start:backOffice_backend": "NODE_ENV=production node dist/src/apps/BackOffice_backend/server",
    "build": "npm run build:clean && npm run build:tsc && npm run build:di",
    "build:tsc": "tsc -p tsconfig.prod.json",
    "build:di": "copy 'src/**/*.{json,yaml}' dist/src",
    "build:clean": "rm -r dist; exit 0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/bson": "^4.0.2",
    "@types/compression": "^1.7.0",
    "@types/convict": "^5.2.1",
    "@types/errorhandler": "1.5.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.6",
    "@types/glob": "^7.1.1",
    "@types/helmet": "0.0.47",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.0",
    "@types/mongodb": "^3.5.18",
    "@types/node": "^14.0.3",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/uuid-validate": "0.0.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "bson": "^4.0.4",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "convict": "^6.0.0",
    "copy": "^0.3.2",
    "errorhandler": "^1.5.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-promise-router": "^4.0.1",
    "glob": "^7.1.6",
    "helmet": "^3.22.0",
    "http-status": "^1.4.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mandrill-api": "^1.0.45",
    "mongodb": "^3.5.7",
    "node-dependency-injection": "^2.6.3",
    "ts-node": "^8.10.1",
    "typescript": "^3.9.2",
    "uuid": "^8.0.0",
    "uuid-validate": "0.0.3",
    "winston": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.51",
    "@types/cucumber": "^6.0.1",
    "@types/faker": "^4.1.12",
    "@types/jest": "^25.2.3",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.9",
    "cucumber": "^6.0.5",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "husky": "^4.2.5",
    "jest": "^26.0.1",
    "lint-staged": "10.2.4",
    "prettier": "^2.0.5",
    "supertest": "^4.0.2",
    "ts-jest": "^26.0.0",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.0.0-pre.44",
    "tslint": "^6.1.2",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "~1.18.0",
    "tslint-eslint-rules": "^5.4.0"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "{src,tests}/**/*.ts": [
      "prettier --write",
      "tslint --fix",
      "git add"
    ]
  }
}
```

** Nota los imports en los archivos de typescript en el backend de node los estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera:

`import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no debes montar la carpeta `node_modules` ni mandar el `package-lock.json` si lo generó el host...

el problema es que hay ciertas librerías que tienen binarios que funcionan en el host pero no dentro de la imagen de docker.

por lo que en el build, se deberían descargar las librerías, y generar el package-lock.json (puedes ponerlo a este archivo bajo control de configuración pero siempre y cuando se haya generado desde dentro del container, y no desde el host)

Comment: Si tienes toda la razón, ha funcionado perfecto. Muchas gracias